# challenging direct traffic using AWS ACL

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, web-application-firewall, amazon-waf

We used to use cloudflare where setting up a challenge for direct traffic is pretty straight forward but we have now moved entirely to AWS cloudfront and for the life of me cannot see a way of setting up a rule to challenge direct traffic with a captcha or challenge

I followed a blog post to setup a referrer channel, but 'Match type' and 'Value to match' do not have the terms required to filter direct traffic

eg match type doesn't have an 'exclude term'
and 'Value to match' cannot contain 'nothing'

Comment: AWS WAF includes Captcha features to protect CloudFront and other resources. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/cloudfront-features.html

Comment: Not any useful information there unfortunately

Comment: Not even [CAPTCHA and Challenge actions in AWS WAF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-captcha-and-challenge.html)?

Comment: No, I know it can do those things. But the issue is setting up the system to challenge only direct traffic